# Could not work out for 3 months due to injury.....Any suggestions?

Tags: injury, health

I had to take a break from working out for 3 months due to Trapezitis(inflammation of Trapezius muscle).

While resuming after a long break, what precautions do I need to take so that I won't encounter the same problem(Trapezitis) again??

Do I need to avoid/add any exercises to get rid of Trapezitis??

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“*itis*” type injuries typically result from overuse.  The overuse can be caused by poor posture, bad exercise form, and, not enough rest between training the affected muscles to name a few reasons.  If you haven't already, you should speak to a Physical Therapist about how to rehab your condition.  A physical therapist will be able to determine the root cause of the problem and suggest ways to resolve your condition.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  Am I the only one that's never heard of this?  There's no areas for impingement I can think of  for your traps......  Who diagnosed you and how - there are no clinical tests for Trapezitis?

Comment: Do urgent MRI to verify if you do not have hernia. If Hernia then do not repeat heavy weights and remove all type of activity cause its serious for life time.